# Accessing a Password-Locked 1997-2003 .XLS?

Tags: microsoft-excel, password-recovery, xls

My father passed away close to a decade ago and I'm trying to access a master file of his that appears to be a 97-2003 password-locked .XLS notebook. None of his known passwords have worked, and I've tried a number of ideas from the internet that I'll explain below, but with no luck. I would greatly appreciate any insight the community can provide!

1. Convert .xls to .zip, open with 7zip, change XML record to unlock notebook. However, the notebook does not have an XML file. There are 4 files, titled Workbook, [1]CompObj, [5]DocumentSummaryInformation, and [5]SummaryInformation. They all appear to be separate .xls files.
2. Hex Editor - I cannot use a Hex Editor because there is no vbaProject.bin file.
3. VBA Macro "PasswordBreaker()" Script - This requires me to open the workbook and Alt-F11 into VBA, but when I do anything but enter a password, everything is greyed out.
4. Accent Office Password Recovery software - didn't work.

At this point I'm not even sure I'm dealing with a normal .xls file, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/how-to-remove-crack-or-break-a-forgotten-excel-xls-password/

Comment: Did you try any paid tools?

Comment: Note that only the _new_ Office 2007-2019 **.xlsx** format documents are Zip files – the older .xls format was not any kind of archive at all. What you're seeing in 7-zip is specifically just 7-zip's own "translation" of CDF file parts into pseudo-files.

Comment: Please put answers in the answer section, not in the question. Only once an answer is selected is the question considered solved by the system. You can select your own answer after 48 hours.

Comment: @DanielB My link-only comment solved the problem, but it isn't really worthy of being an answer. Not sure why you rolled it back, the question should just have been closed I think.

Comment: You may still be able to delete the question if you desire. If not, you could flag it for moderators to do it. // Even recommending services or software can be on-topic if done correctly, so I encourage you to make it a proper answer.

Comment: @DanielB We probably won't see OP ever again.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Thought OP wrote it.

Comment: I'm still here! But I can't figure out how to mark a comment as the answer, supposedly there is a check box next to the comments but I don't see any such box.

Comment: @Medmankms Sorry, this website is about as userfriendly as a poisonous potato which happens to be on fire. I've heard there is a 48 hour waiting period before you can accept your own answer. I don't know why. https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately used passwordlastic.com, which was able to unlock a portion of the spreadsheet. I paid $30 for a license and received the full unlocked sheet, so I have found a resolution to this issue.